# how to create an internal file once application is installed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like create a file in internal storage once the application is installed. in fact I would like to have an internal storage when I run my function. but I don't know how, I use a service or an activity and how. i used the code below in the `onCreate()` of my main activity. but the problem once my application start run i check my file, it is empty the data that it contain was erased.

```
String file_name = "profil1.txt";
        String file_name1 = "profil2.txt";
        File f = new File("file_name");
        try {
            if(f.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "les fichiers sont deja cree");
            }else {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                FileOutputStream fos1 = openFileOutput(file_name1, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);   

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: So as I can see you want to copy a file to internal memory, right? If that, where is stored your profil1.txt and where exactly you want to store your profil2.txt ?

Comment: i cheked i write in data/data/package/files/..., and when i do cat i have data in my file but to read form i have a problem. and when i close my app and start it the file is empty

Comment: sorry but i really didn't get what you mean...

Comment: i put my creat file in the method Oncreat of the main activity. i write in this file using an other activity. but when i would like to read in this file, the file is empty, i chek using cat my path/file i have stored data. and when i restart my application it will erase data in file.

Answer (score 1):

Change `File f = new File("file_name");` to

`File f = new File(file_name);`